# Higher order functions scala

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Suppose we have this function definition and invocation:

```
def sayHello(prefix:String):(String => String) = {
  n => s"$prefix $n"
}

val greeting = sayHello("Hello")
greeting("Gio")
```

Using Intellij, I see the **variable "n" inside function is of type String**.

**Why a variable not declared before is inferred by Scala as String?**

I understand this **higher order function** returns a function `String => String`, but I can't see relationship between these two concepts.

Could you provide me a clarification about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "name not found" ?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: "Scala has a built-in type inference mechanism which allows the programmer to omit certain type annotations": https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/local-type-inference.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` in your example is not a variable. It's an argument (slight semantic difference). `n => x` notation represents a function accepting n and returning x.

Since you defined a return value of your `sayHello` to be a function `String` => `String`, the only thing you can return here is a function taking a `String` and returning a `String`. That's why you can skip the argument type for your `n`. With the current definition of `sayHello` it's clear, `n` can only be a `String`.

If you didn't define the return type of `sayHello`, scala would require you to give the type of the `n` argument, as it can't possibly infer it from the function definiton:

```scala
def sayHello(prefix:String) = {
    n: String => s"$prefix $n"
}
```

In the above example, the return value of `sayHello` is inferred from its body to be `String => String`.